# trouble with some data displaying from mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Hopefully you can overflow me with knowledge...

I'm creating a bus timetable viewer app and I need some help!!! I am working through this tutorial [The Dead-Simple Step-By-Step Guide for Front-End Developers to Getting Up and Running With Node.JS, Express, and MongoDB](https://closebrace.com/tutorials/2017-03-02/the-dead-simple-step-by-step-guide-for-front-end-developers-to-getting-up-and-running-with-nodejs-express-and-mongodb) for a basic node.js app and modifying to my needs.

I have so far successfully completed setup and connected the mongoDB to the app. My app can read the imported data and return a list of stuff (this is good! progress!!) However I am struggling to retrieve the bus number from the data and display it, it shows as "undefined". All other fields display fine (route, bus stop, start, finish)

Why is that? Is it because bus number is a number? Do I need to convert it to a string for it to be defined and show up in a list?

Mongo db sample:

```
{
    "Bus":"1",
    "Route":"Casuarina (Hospital Precinct)",
    "Start":"Casuarina",
    "Stop1":"Hospital Precinct",
    "Stop2":"Tiwi",
    "Stop3":"Brinkin",
    "Stop4":"Nakara",
    "Stop5":"NO STOP",
    "Finish":"Casuarina",
    "Times":"https://nt.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0009/159309/route-1-public-bus-timetable.pdf",
    "Maps":"https://nt.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/159308/route-1-public-bus-map.pdf"
}
```

Code from .ejs file that displays current list on page:

```
<body>
    <h1>Bus List</h1>
    <ul>
        <%
            var list = '';
            for (i = 0; i < buslist.length; i++) {
                list += '<li><a href="busTimes' + buslist[i].Times + '">' 
                + buslist[i].Route + '</a></li>';
            }
        %>
        <%- list %>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <%
            var list = '';
            for (i = 0; i < buslist.length; i++) {
                list += '<li><a href="busTimes' + buslist[i].Maps + '">' 
                + buslist[i].Bus + '</a></li>';
            }
        %>
        <%- list %>
    </ul>
</body>
```

RESULT:

```
Bus List

Casuarina (Hospital Precinct)
Casuarina 
Casuarina
Casuarina to Darwin
Darwin to Casuarina
Casuarina to Darwin
Darwin to Casuarina


undefined
undefined
undefined
```

I also want to find a way to take the https links from the mongo data, have them point to the associated pdf document and display it in the app. This will be the next challenge, so if you have any idea how to do that I would appreciate it!!

The overall aim will be to have user select button/s for search by (#, route, start, stops, finish) - filter that list to get the one they want - display bus time or map pdf based on selection.

any pointers welcome! thanks peeps!

Comment: Can you share the mongo query you are running? Also, it would be a good idea to print the whole buslist object while testing either on the server side or in the `.ejs` file. Can you share that output as well? Helps in debugging.

Comment: `Do I need to convert it to a string for it to be defined and show up in a list?`
This is very easy thing to test, just stringify it and see if it actually helps. Much easier and quicker than asking on SO and waiting for a reply :)